# Points below or above the curve using R

Tags: r

I try to figure out, if my point is below or above a simple curve and struggling with my math at the moment, I guess...

I prepared a working example, but the math first.

I have some points and I want to check if they are above or below a curve. The curve has the function `y=1/(x-.5)`. So I thought I will set the function to 0 and get `0=1/(x-.5)-y`.

Afterwards I will get negative values if the point is on one side of the curve, and positive values on the other side.

I realised a problem, if the x values is smaller then .5, then the part below 1/ gets negative and all my values are also negative.

I added a special point (5) which gives the expected positive value, but how about the other ones, how should I test those?

```
points <- data.frame(
  x=c(-3.6030515,-0.2791478,10.2045860,-0.7457344,1,0.4037591,0.1555678,
      6.1525442,1.9831603),
  y=c(0.95715140,0.18139107,2.87456154,0.17190597,0.5,0.09778570,0.02708183,
      2.69455955,1.09943870)
)
curves <- data.frame(x=c(seq(.1,10,.1)))
curves$y <- 1/(curves$x-.5)

plot(points$x,points$y)
lines(curves$x,curves$y)
lines(-curves$x,curves$y)

1/(points$x-.5)-points$y >= 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count the number below the curve :

```
## count the number below the curve 
sum(points$y<1/(points$x-0.5) )
```

To show it graphically :

```
## plot it using plot and curve
plot(points$x,points$y,col=ifelse(points$y<1/(points$x-0.5) ,'blue','red'),pch=20)
curve(1/(x-.5),-4,10,add=TRUE,col='green',lwd=2)
```

[image]

### discontinuity part :

To show the discontinuity part graphically you should use `curve`:

```
curve(1/(x-.5),0,1,col='green',lwd=2)
abline(v=0.5,lwd=3)
```

[image]
`

Answer (score 1):

Unless I've misunderstood the question, you should be able to just evaluate the function at your points' `x` values, and compare the outcome (i.e. the `y` value according to the function) to your points' `y` values.

```
f <- function(x) 1 / (x-0.5)
f(points$x) < points$y

# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

With the way I've structured the inequality, `TRUE` indicates that the curve is below the corresponding `y` value in the `points` vector. In other words, all but the fifth point are above the curve.

Comment: Have you plot the example I gave? you can see 4 points above the curve... The one point you pointed out is the single one where the (x-.5) doesn't get negative and at the same time is below the curve...
when (x-.5) gets negative, the function will report TRUE as well, even if the point is below and not above...

Comment: You realise this is a discontinuous function, right? Run `curve(1/(x-0.5))` and you will see that there is an asymptote at x = 0.5. Any point with an x value below 0.5, and a non-negative y-value, is in fact above the function. In retrospect I see that you were tackling the problem the right way, but I think maybe you didn't realise this key point.

Comment: I think that was the math part, I was talking about :-) Do you have any solution, how to solve my problem. I am working with `1/abs(x-.5)-y` at the moment. Look like it solves my problem. But I am not sure if I forgot some math theory again... Thanks for pointing out the exact problem!

Comment: So now I'm not sure what the problem is - doesn't this resolve it? I'm not sure why you'd take the absolute value. The "upper part" of the function (i.e. the L-shaped curve) doesn't exist below x=0.5. Pretending that a point to the left of x=0.5 is in fact to the right of x=0.5 doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I was just looking for the exact mathematical expression. I guessed my 'absolute solution' is just a workaround. Actually it seems to work in the way I think, but I am not sure if this is mathematically correct... Since I want to count all values below .5 also as 'not above the curve', I think this is an easy solution, isn't it? The other solution would be to test if `x<.5` and if so define as below the curve... Not sure what is the best solution...

Comment: Yes, points with x < 0.5 are not above the part of the curve that you're thinking about. But they're not below it either ;)

Comment: actually, this was the right comment :-) And also the graph agstudy help to understand it :) Thanks again